# Which one is better ini or json to store hard code data on the server?

Tags: python, json, django

I have some data which I need to keep hard code in my project (quite big data), which is likely to be settings of my form. its structure is like this:

```
{X : [{a,b}, {c,d}], Y:[{e,f},{g,h}], Z: [{i,j},{k,l}], ...}
```

What is the good way to store it hard code, In `Json` or in `ini` or something else?
Keeping all this in `settings.py` is not good I guess!

Comment: If it requires nesting, then you can't use ini files. Other options are json, pickling, a key/value store (like memcache/redis).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid No nesting, these are key value pairs.
I can use in ini like:
[X]
a=b
c=d

[Y]
e=f
g=h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it requires nesting, then you can't use ini files.

Other options are json, pickling, a key/value store (like memcache/redis). If it will require modifications, then don't use the disk. Doing so will also make your code incompatible with many PaaS providers that do not have a "filesystem" that you can use.

My recommendations:

1. Use a k/v store (like memcache/redis).  You don't need to serialize (convert) your data, the APIs are very straight forward and if you go with redis you can store complicated data structures easily. Plus, it will be very *very* fast.
2. json and pickling have the same problem; in that you need to use the filesystem.  Hits to the file system will slow your execution time down and you will have problems if you want to deploy to heroku or similar as they don't provide file system access. The other problem you will have is you may need to write your own conversion code (serializers) if you plan on storing some custom objects that can't be easily converted. If you want to use json, my recommendation is to store it in a database.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! Now I understand. As per your suggestion using redis or memcache is good for my project. This is what I was expecting!
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of "quite big data" and the frequency which it will be changed.

If your settings don't change very often you could use a simple file in the format you like the most. If you go this route I'd recommend taking a look at [this project](https://github.com/emre/kaptan) (it supports multiple formats: dict, json, yaml, .ini)

If you'll be constantly making changes to those settings and your data is actually very big (several thousand lines or something like that) you'll probably want to use a proper database or some other storage which provides a better interface for programatically editing those settings. If you're already using some kind of database for your application's non-settings data, why not use it for this as well?

It's true you could read huge settings from a file but it'll probably be easier to interact with those settings if they're stored in a database.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the *simplest* ways to do this are using straight Python code, pkl, or JSON.

JSON is very easy to load:

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

And so is pkl:

```
import pickle

with open('data.pkl', 'r') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

To generate the pkl file:

```
with open('data.pkl', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(your_data, f)
```

Comment: I know how to do access the data, but I'm not much sure what is efficient to use. data is hard code and won't change at all